# upgrade xcode14 error build: Dependency for P1:target-

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode14

[image]

Does anyone have the same problem?how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution for this, I am also facing the problem

Answer (score 3):

We found this error because we used a colon : in the project's name. Can recreate the error by creating a new Xcode project and naming it anything with a colon : included. Then try to run it on simulator.

Comment: I had a file which has colon in its name and your answer helped me to build my project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The old project previously had SWIFT_SWIFT3_OBJC_INFERENCE set in buildSettings. Delete this configuration and the project will run normally